# Is it possible that North or South poles are mythical continent Atlántida?

Tags: earth

Is it possible that Earth was positioned like this sometime in history with current North and South poles positioned around equator:
- http://screencast.com/t/cZGmxf1XTt6
- http://screencast.com/t/FRpih6KMJvst ?

Based on theory and idea of Earth's magnetic shifts, an idea crossed my mind that frozen North or South poles holds ancient and lost Atlántida continent bellow thick ice.

If Earth position was not the same during history, Atlántida would be somewhere around Earth's equator and that would allow ancient non-necessarily human race to evolve and progress. Another magnetic shift and change of Earth's position would instantly destroy everything built and ancient secrets would be hidden currently under the poles.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about world building, but a question about the real world. Please see the [help center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. This question is probably more appropriate for the [Earth Science Stack Exchange](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Azuaron questions about the real world are not necessarily off-topic on this site, please see [this meta question](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3872/is-a-real-world-question-off-topic) (and if you disagree with the provided answer, post your own explaining your reasoning, this has been a point of contention in the past but the general consensus is usually that real-world questions are on-topic).

Comment: Given that the question does not mention any imaginary world they are building, I'm sticking with my assessment.

Answer (score 2):

About 450 million years go, Antarctica *was* on the Equator, because of continental drift: http://discoveringantarctica.org.uk/oceans-atmosphere-landscape/ice-land-and-sea/tectonic-history-into-the-deep-freeze/

If you want to have the remains of <s>shoggoths</s> an ancient pre-human race beneath the ice, go right ahead.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cm5giPd5Uro gives a useful visual

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

There is a continent under Antartica Ice sheets.

Antarctica, like all continents moved and were in different place in the path, but they were also in different shapes and connected differently. The world pretty goes through cycles of Single Super-continent -> multiple Continents -> Single Super-Continent. The reason for this and how are all pretty well understood, but outside the scope of the question.

There is no continent under the ice of the "North Pole".

---

There is a pseudo-science idea of crust slip which supposedly, periodically, the crust slips all in one direction which causes mass extinctions. This is utter nonsense, but some people believe it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. The earth 's poles are cold due to their position relative to the sun rather than the magnetic field. The magnetic field would not cause the pole's to become cold. The magnetic field flipping seems to have little impact on life. An advanced species such as humans would be effected by a field flip as many technologies use earths magnetic field but the flip would not destroy our civilisation. Furthermore a civilisation couldn't be hidden under the Arctic as most of the Arctic is pure ice floating on the sea with no land for the civilisation to be built on.